# Sum up a Column in dplyr with Int and Null

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dplyr table and would like to know sum for each columns.
My table may looks like this

```
A B C
1 0 9 
6 8 6
4 5 6
NULL 4 6
```

I've tried using `summarise` function, but it saids

```
no applicable method for 'summarise_' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

Basically I want a new table, with sum of A, sum of B and sum of C

Comment: A column cannot have the value `NULL`, neither entirely or a single value. Your dplyr table (data.frame, matrix, or tribble) is not what you think it is. Try looking at it with the `str` function, and update your question with the output from `dput`.

Comment: Did you add the NULL value manually beforehand? Could you update your post including ```dput(yourdata)``` and the code to create it? If you added NULL manually, add NA instead and you can summarize with ```sum(..., na.rm = T) ```

Comment: ```structure(list(A = c("1", "6", "4", "NULL"), B = c(0, 8, 5, 4
), C = c(9, 6, 6, 6)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = integer(0), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000002811eb61ef0>)```

Comment: Thanks guys, The na.rm=T worked...!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I created your data table and   then made A as numeric. H is a vector that sums up the three columns of Z.

```
z <- data.table()
z$A = c(1,6,4,"NULL")
z$B = c(0,8,5,4)  
z$C = c(9,6,6,6)
z$A <- as.numeric(z$A)

H <- z %>%
  mutate(h = ifelse(is.na(A), B+C, ifelse(is.na(B), A+C, ifelse(is.na(C), A+B, A+B+C )))) %>%
  select(h)
```